# Need TFS to just take my lock for files away

Tags: tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2015

Here is the information about the development environment pertaining to my work computer:

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

I checked out some projects from our company's TFS server.
I go the lock for the various solution files (.sln), however, it prevents other programmers from committing code.

I right-clicked on the solution file (.sln), and clicked "Undo Pending Changes..." because I thought the aforementioned steps would release the lock.

However, I get the following warning for a bunch of files within the solution folder:

> The item 'blahblah.cs' is already under source control at the selected
>   location. If you are trying to rebind a project that you have already
>   added to source control outside Microsoft Visual Studio, you should
>   use the Change Source Control command. If you are adding this project
>   for the first time, you should either choose a different server folder
>   for the project or move the existing project to a different server
>   folder.

-Why is the said message assuming that I'm trying to rebind the project that's already in source control?

-In any case, I just want to release the lock, how do I go about releasing the lock?

Answer (score 1):

> To unlock a folder or file from Source Control Explorer
>
> 1.On the **View *menu, choose *Other Windows**,and then choose **Source Control Explorer**.
>
> 2.In Source Control Explorer, open the shortcut menu for the folder or file from which you want to remove a lock, and then choose **Unlock**.

Note: If you haven't check the lock status under Pending Changes, you need to check in the pending changes first. More detailed info from MSDN: [Lock and unlock folders or files](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/tfvc/lock-unlock-folders-files)

You can also use [tfs lock command](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/tfvc/lock-command) to unlock files or folders such as `c:\projects>tf lock /lock:none src/`